# `SyntaxError` in if-else one-liner

Tags: python, dictionary, if-statement, syntax, conditional-operator

I wrote this block of code, but it doesn't work because of `SyntaxError`.

```py
def char_freq(message):
    d = dict()
    for ch in message:
        d[ch] += 1 if ch in d else d[ch] = 1
    return d                             ^ SyntaxError: End of statement expected
```

I don't know how to rewrite the expression in order to keep if-else in one line and to get it to work.

I know it is possible to implement the function as a simple `for` loop, but I  don't understand, why my if-else one-liner results in `SyntaxError`?

Comment: d[ch] = (d[ch] + 1) if ch in d else 1. You should try this.

Comment: Thanks, it works. But I don't understand why notation in my question doesn't work.

Comment: the syntax is like ->
a = <value-1> if <expression> else <value-2>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you asked to keep the `if/else` Do

```
d[ch] = (d[ch] + 1) if ch in d else 1
```

---

But the `dict.get()` syntax is nicer   `d[ch] = d.get(ch, 0) + 1`

Or a `collections.defaultdict` with `int` factory

```
def char_freq(message):
    d = defaultdict(int)
    for ch in message:
        d[ch] += 1
    return d
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm still curious, why my notation results in error?

Comment: @EvgeniyGolovin you can't do assignement in if/else parts

Answer (score 2):

Turn `d` into a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) and then you can just ignore the statement altogether

```
from collections import defaultdict
def char_freq(message):
    d = defaultdict(int)
    for ch in message:
        d[ch] += 1
    return d
```

It also looks like you're just counting characters so you could just use a [counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
from collections import Counter
def char_freq(message):
    return Counter(message)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, great ways to improve my code!